# Reliability of a compression barb fitting for a water hose

Tags: plumbing, water, hose

I just installed water lines to a Brondell's bidet attachment. Cold water is supplied by the regular braided hose with compression 3/8 fittings. For hot water, however, they use a single barb fitting with a compression nut over a 1/4 thread over the barb, with no ferrule. The hose is, according to the company, *thermoplastic polyurethane and is rated for boiling temperatures (100 degrees Celcius) and water pressures up to 150 PSI.* I cannot tell the hardness of the material, but it is softer that the nylon tubing you'd normally find in ice maker lines that also use a compression mount (w/o barb with a ferrule tho), but harder that flexible Tyvec I use in my 50 PSI air applications at work. The hose is noticeably hard to cut with my lab hose cutter, which I use to cut 95A 5/32 polyurethane tubing for 150PSI pneumatics, so, given the larger diameter of the Bidell's line, I think it's no less than 85A. The Brondell's hose is a bit more flexible even with it's larger, 1/4 OD.

The proprietary tee can be seen in this video, if you do not mind watching a few seconds of it, where this exact connection is assembled: https://youtu.be/DyVE2R4DGAw?t=2m8s

My question is, **how reliable this connection is for exposed plumbing?** Every time I open/close the faucet or the bidet, the line shudders a little, so there is a bit of movement everywhere, including connection points. I am worrying one day the connector will decide to just spit out the tube and cause a flood (my lab air has no such concern). I just had a flood from an unrelated leak in in-wall plumbing, so I am nervous about leaks; sorry if I am overzealous. I tested my assembly by pulling on the mounted line not quite gently while pressurized, but it still stayed.

Another concern, I used silicone oil on all gaskets (Buna-N, I believe, some non-silicone rubber 100% certainly) while mounting the brass hardware, which is a common assembly practice in the lab. Thus the tee had some oil on surface when I installed the plastic line. Should I better disassemble and degrease this hose mounting part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question: I disassembled the connection with the purpose of removing possible traces of leftover silicone oil from it. When I removed the compression nut and pulled the tube off the barb, I noticed that the end of the tube has become noticeably flared, because the compression nut, well, compressed it and pulled somewhat forward on the barb. Since the tubing is on the hard side, I am sure **this natural flaring alone is more than adequate to prevent the tube from coming off the barb through the retaining nuts**, despite some hydraulic hammering from faucet operation and jiggling of the tubing caused by it.

I wanted to post a picture, but the transparent tubing material did not allow for a good snapshot.